# Swift/iOs: How to link dynamically added table cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Still taking babysteps with swift.

With a static tableview i just ctrl+drag the table cell to the right navigation controller and the select view/scene is displayed.

But how i can achieve this if i am using Table view with "Dynamic Prototypes"? I filled the table view like so

```
 let testMenu = [

        (“menuItem 1"),
        ("menuItem test"),
        (“afd"),
        (“test"),
        (“barca"),
        (“london")

    ]

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 1
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return testMenu.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let (menuItem) = testMenu[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = menuItem

        return cell

    }
```

This will display the menu items as expected. But linking each table cell to the right navigation controller isn't clear to me. Looking at some tutorial i guess i need to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but trying out the following didn't print anything and i don't know how to create the link, segue?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //CODE TO BE RUN ON CELL TOUCH
    //need to go to the right navigation controller

    print("clicked: \(indexPath)")
}
```

And the class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
```

EDIT 1: i am able to print "clicked:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}" . Within the connection inspector i had to drag the outlets : delegate -> to the view controller

Answer (score 0):

You should use the didSelectRowAtIndexPath to push the right View Controller in current View Controller's navigation Controller.

(For Your Information, each View Controller has a inbuilt navigationController)

Using the method, pushViewController() of navigationController class you can push any View Controller in the current view controller's navigationController, and then the further processing of view should be done in the pushed view controller.

If you want the pushed view controller to know the indexPath of the current View Controller's table View, just make the pushed View controller, a custom view Controller with a property of type NSIndexPath.

Initialize the property in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath() , during the initialisation of the object of rightViewController that you are going to push in.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //Before doing this, import the custom view controller that you want to push inside your navigation controller
 //1. Create the object of CustomRightViewController which is a subclass of UIViewController
 let rightViewController = CustomRightViewController();

 //2. Set its myIndexPath property to selected index path , but before doing this, you must declare the myIndexPath property in your CustomRightViewController.swift file 
 rightViewController.myIndexPath = indexPath; 

 //3. Now you can push this Custom View Controller in your current View Controller's navigationController
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(rightViewController, animated: true);

 //4. After this you can program the Custom View Controller accordingly, with the indexPath or any other object if you want to use from the current/initial View Controller.   

}
```

Comment: I am not much familiar with swift, I am an objective C developer, still wait for a while I will try to figure out...

Comment: You can see the above code, if you find any more difficulty, plz comment here